# Aligning music notes using String matching algorithms or Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, evaluation, string-matching

I need to compare 2 sets of musical pieces (i.e. a playing-taken in MIDI format-note details extracted and saved in a database table, against sheet music-taken into XML format). When evaluating playing against sheet music (i.e.note details-pitch, duration, rhythm), note alignment needs to be done - to identify missed/extra/incorrect/swapped notes that from the reference (sheet music) notes.

I have like 1800-2500 notes in one piece approx (can even be more-with polyphonic, right now I'm doing for monophonic). So will I have to have all these into an array? Will it be memory overloading or stack overflow?

There are string matching algorithms like KMP, Boyce-Moore. But note alignment can also be done through Dynamic Programming. How can I use Dynamic Programming to approach this? What are the available algorithms? Is it about approximate string matching?

Which approach is much productive? String matching algos like Boyce-Moore, or dynamic programming? How can I assess which is more effective?

Greatly appreciate any insight or suggestions
Thanks in advance

Comment: To be a little clearer perhaps you could explain what exactly note alignment is.  Most of us here know more about computers than we do about music.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Pace. What I mean by Note alignment is this. I need to compare the player's playing (i.e. played notes) against the notes in sheetmusic w.r.t pitch, duration, rhythm & onset information. If I simply do note-by-note comparison, suppose the student player 1.slipped a note (missing/deletion), or 2.played an additional note(addition)/or 3.played the wrong note(incorrect/mismatch) -> these won't be identified. So I need to align notes of the student's playing (I have note details extracted from MIDI), with the actual(sheetmusic) in order to compare/evaluate. Is that clearer?

Comment: Do let me know if further explanation of the problem is required. Greatly appreciate your concern Pace.
Advance Thanks

Comment: Seems like an application of Longest increasing subsequence.

Comment: I think I understand what you're after. I can see some possible value in comparing (in a gross way) a student's execution versus what is on the printed page, but jeesh, if I wanted pitch, duration, rhythm, and onset to *exactly* match, I'd let the computer do that playing rather than a human. And I'm not sure I'd consider it music any more than the stuff that comes out of a drum-machine is "music". Musicianship / musicality, is largely the ability to interpret and bend the pitch, duration, rhythm, and onset of what might otherwise be wooden and soul-less. Jazz, classical whatever - still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question - I think this [paper](http://www.dlib.org/dlib/may97/meldex/05witten.html) covers a lot of what you're interested in.  They address the issue of errors and music alignment and discuss their results using DP as a solver.  They introduce an algorithm called "fast approximate matching" which they claim is better than the DP approach.

It looks like the key authors to use in a search are Mongeau & Sankoff.  It would appear that their original paper set off a lot of work in this area.

Neat stuff.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Grembo. I'll read up and contact for any clarifications.

Comment: Can I pls find some link for sample source code to try dynamic programming for approximate string matching? What is the most efficient dynamic programming algorithm (like in exact string matching algo->boyer-moore)?

Comment: Thanks Grembo for the link you sent last-that was useful. It's about Local and Global alignment. Local alignment (e.g. Smith-Waterman algorithm) is more suitable for my approach. But there's also Levenshtein distance to find edit distance (i.e. # of edit operations needed to match text against pattern). How can I justify one against the other? Which is better? After finding edit distance, what is a better approach to align the notes? Is it by just referring by the array index or are there other alternatives? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just ran across this interesting idea applied to the subject:  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.87&rep=rep1&type=pdf